# Proof that (S(X),$\circ$) is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

$X$ is a non-empty set and $S$(X) := {*f* : X $\rightarrow$ X : *f* is bijective}. Investigate if (S(X),$\circ$) is a group. Notes: *f* is bijective which means that the function is also injective and surjective. My solution:

Let *f, g* and *h* $\in$ S(X) be arbitrary. (*f* $\circ$ *g*)$\circ$ *h* = *f* $\circ$(*g* $\circ$ *h*) (Associative). Let x $\in$ X be arbitrary so that:
((*f* $\circ$ *g*) $\circ$ *h*) (x) = (*f* $\circ$ (*g* $\circ$ *h*))(x) = *f* $\circ$ *g*(*h*(x)) = *f* (*g*(*h*(x)) and (*f* $\circ$ (*g* $\circ$ *h*))(x) = *f* (*g*(*h*(x)).

Now for the neutral element: Let *f* be arbitrary and let's assume that there exists I$_X$ (Identity of X). (*f* $\circ$ I$_X$) (x) = *f* (I$_X$(x)). And (I$_X$ $\circ$ *f*) (x) = I$_X$(*f*(x)). I don't know how to continue at this point. I somehow think that my solutions aren't correct and I still need to prove that (S(X),$\circ$) has an inverse element but I don't know how.

Any hints or solutions guiding to the right direction I much appreciate.

Comment: Fix a bijection $f$ in $S(X)$, then the inverse function is the needed symmetrical element with respect to composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. For the neutral element: indeed you need the identity map. Then $\mathrm{Id}\circ f(x)=\mathrm{Id}(f(x))=f(x)=f(\mathrm{Id}(x))$ for all $x\in X$, by definition of the identity map.

Then for the inverse, every bijective function has an inverse, so because $f$ is a bijection there exists a two-sided inverse $f^{-1}$.

Note that you also need to check that the composite of two bijections $X\to X$ is again a bijection $X\to X$.

Then, together with associativity, which you already checked, you conclude $S(X)$ is a group, using composition of maps $\circ$ as the operation.